Power BI filter table by slicer dates from relationship table
I am trying to get a list of items labelled "Closed" in a table in PowerBI, i can get the count number with the below code but can not get individual items on separate rows
my dates are held in one table and filter out items in another table
has anyone managed this?
X_TBF_Closed = 
VAR _StartDate2 = SELECTEDVALUE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date],FIRSTDATE('PowerBi Period 
Dates'[Date]))
VAR _EndDate2 = SELECTEDVALUE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date],LASTDATE('PowerBi Period 
Dates'[Date]))
VAR _Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER ( ALL (Task_Brief_List ), Task_Brief_List[Date 
of Task] >= _StartDate2 && Task_Brief_List[Date of Task] <= _EndDate2+1 && 
Task_Brief_List[Approval Status]="Closed")
)
RETURN
IF (ISBLANK(
     _count ),
      0, 
      _count )




If you place the item in the row just before the measure, do they not show?

Can you please share some data/your model ?

Hi, No i jest get a blank table i have now tried
VAR _StartDate2 = SELECTEDVALUE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date],FIRSTDATE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date]))
VAR _EndDate2 = SELECTEDVALUE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date],LASTDATE('PowerBi Period Dates'[Date]))
VAR Search_Results=
CALCULATE (VALUES(
Task_Brief_List[Approval Status]) ,
Task_Brief_List[Date of Task] >= _StartDate2 && Task_Brief_List[Date of Task] <= _EndDate2+1 && ask_Brief_List[Approval Status]="Closed")
RETURN
Search_Results

Hi, Screen shot of data model added
